# How to Change ActionBarSherlock Search View icons and color

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

How to change the Search View Background color and the icons ?

[image: ActionBar Sherlock]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling a SearchView in Android Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527636/styling-a-searchview-in-android-action-bar)

Comment: I tried but the solution not working

Comment: Then post the code that you have tried, describe what you observe, and explain why what you observe isn't what you expect.

Comment: Yes. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16971484/1253844) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i did the same adding in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
            <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/my_close_icon</item>
            <item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/my_search_icon</item>
            <item name="searchAutoCompleteTextView">@style/searchTextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="searchTextView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.SearchAutoCompleteTextView">
            <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
            <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/red</item>
    </style>
```

More info: 
**[couldn't change actionbarsherlock SearchView icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971359/couldnt-change-actionbarsherlock-searchview-icon)**

Update:

**[Text color of SearchView in ActionBar with ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923442/text-color-of-searchview-in-actionbar-with-actionbarsherlock)**